# having more than one jqwidget tab issue

Tags: javascript

i have the following in my HEAD section. the second one, jqxTabsExam, doesnt work unless i remove the first one, jqxTabsExam, then the first one doesnt work obviously, so that is why i think im not activating it correctly here in this section. any ideas?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 
 
        $(document).ready(function () {
   

            // Create jqxTabsMain.
            $('#jqxTabsMain').jqxTabs({ width: '100%', position: 'top', animationType: 'fade', selectionTracker: true});
            $('#settings div').css('margi,n-top', '10px');
            $('#animation').jqxCheckBox({ theme: theme });
            $('#contentAnimation').jqxCheckBox({ theme: theme });
   
          $('#animation').on('change', function (event) {
           var checked = event.args.checked;
           $('#jqxTabsMain').jqxTabs({ selectionTracker: checked });
          
          });
   
   
      $('#contentAnimation').on('change', function (event) {
       var checked = event.args.checked;
       if (checked) {
        $('#jqxTabsMain').jqxTabs({ animationType: 'fade' });
       }
       else {
        $('#jqxTabsMain').jqxTabs({ animationType: 'none' });
       }
      });
      
                //done with first tab 
      
   
   
         // Create jqxTabsExam.
            $('#jqxTabsExam').jqxTabs({ width: '100%', position: 'top', animationType: 'fade', selectionTracker: true});
            $('#settings div').css('margi,n-top', '10px');
            $('#animationExam').jqxCheckBox({ theme: theme });
            $('#contentAnimationExam').jqxCheckBox({ theme: theme });
   
         $('#animationExam').on('change', function (event) {
        var checked = event.args.checked;
        $('#jqxTabsExam').jqxTabs({ selectionTracker: checked });
       
       });
   
   
   
             
          $('#contentAnimationExam').on('change', function (event) {
           var checked = event.args.checked;
           if (checked) {
            $('#jqxTabsExam').jqxTabs({ animationType: 'fade' });
           }
           else {
            $('#jqxTabsExam').jqxTabs({ animationType: 'none' });
           }
          });
  
            //done with second tab 
   
           
   
        });
    </script>
```

the second one doesn't work, unless i remove the fist one,jqxTabsExam, in the function

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [Tabs Integration](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtabs/integration.htm?arctic) to view how to add widgets inside Tabs using the [jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/) Tabs widget.